# Build a device that can set voltage according to intensity of the light shined

Tags: electrical-resistance, voltage

I want to build a device that uses photodiodes and photoresistors to set the voltage in the circuit that shines a bulb. The idea is simple. When the light is intense, the bulb should shine less, when the light is less intense the bulb should shine more. How can I build that device?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it belongs on the [electronics stack exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Do some research on photodiode resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the bulb emits in the visible wavelength regime, then you can use a silicon photodiode.  Depending upon the particulars of your "bulb" you could put the photodiode in series with a resistor and put that combination in parallel with the bulb.  So as the photodiode receives more light, it's resistance will decrease thereby allowing current to flow in that part of the circuit, and away from the bulb.  This assumes that you are using a constant current source.

Comment: This would require a very expensive very large area photodiode. It may work with a well tuned combination of solar cells and the right lightbulb... but I doubt it will work all that well because of the characteristics of light bulbs and the logarithmic response of the human eye.